# MongoDB Limits : Slow to insert records after 250 million

Tags: mongodb, windows-server-2016

So I have installed the latest MongoDb on to a Windows 2016 server, it has been going like grease lighting up until I hit around 250 million records (2 fields, URL, body text, 1 index on the URL), now inserting takes a lot longer (from seconds to minutes).

Fast disks (SAN), plenty of ram (it's using 64gb out of 128gb), is there some sort of limit?

My aim is to insert 2.8 billion records.

**Mongo 4.2 Windows Server 2016 DC**

[image]
[image]
The data is simply ID/URL/Body index on URL

CFG (default)

> ## mongod.conf
>
> ## for documentation of all options, see:
>
> ## http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
>
> ## Where and how to store data. storage:   dbPath: Z:\data   journal:
>
> ```
> enabled: true
> ```
>
> ## engine:
>
> ## mmapv1:
>
> ## wiredTiger:
>
> ## where to write logging data. systemLog:   destination: file   logAppend: true   path:  C:\Program
>
> Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\log\mongod.log
>
> ## network interfaces net:   port: 27017   bindIp: 192.168.0.150,127.0.0.1
>
> ## processManagement:
>
> ## security:
>
> ## operationProfiling:
>
> ## replication:
>
> ## sharding:
>
> ### Enterprise-Only Options:
>
> ## auditLog:
>
> ## snmp:

Comment: More information needed. Look at the system and identify whether it is CPU, memory or disk bound to start.

Comment: None of them seem to be even busy

Comment: You are saying your system is idle for more than 1 minute when you are doing an insert?

Comment: Yes 128gb DDR, 64 Cores not even going above 5%, NAS writing 5/6meg.  I think its hit an Index limit or somethign

Comment: The available filesystems su... re are ill suited for larger installations of MongoDB. From my experience, you get the best results [with XFS tweaked according to MongoDB's production notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#mongodb-on-linux). Aside from that, URL's by definition are unique, so you have a spurious index on   URL, because you could use the URL as `_id`: `{_id:"https://example.com/foo/bar?baz=1", body:"Hello, 1"}`. One index saved, should save RAM somewhere in the area of 3GB (250m * 12b, assuming you use an ObjectID as `_id`).

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using? Also, please add your configuration to your question [by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61593340/edit)

Comment: Thank you for the great info, it's on Windows so XFS isn't an option I believe

Comment: These graphs are a good start. Next step is to run the graphs throughout both phases (fast & slow) and mark the transition point. What is changing? Then, look in the server logs for any entries that indicate background activity and such that may be going on around the transition point.

Comment: Do you think it could be a Windows issue?

Comment: It _could_ be anything. You need to follow a troubleshooting process to get to the bottom of the issue. Are you doing this for work? Most people don't have 4 socket servers in their living rooms. Find a coworker that understands databases in general and can debug issues, bribe them if necessary, ask them to sit at the computer and figure this out and observe what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there some sort of limit?

MongoDB limits are described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/).

MongoDB does not limit its own *performance*.

Comment: I can't find anything in there which would tell me why its slowing down